# boot for install crashes on 14.04 (Display related)

Tags: boot, system-installation, ati, display

Situation: I'm trying to install 14.04 on an ASUS R510DP laptop.

Preconditions: I checked my install media and MD5 sum matches.  Booting to check install media passes on the USB Drive.

Symptoms: During the install phase, the screen flickers 3 times and the ubuntu logo pops up and continues to load.  It seems like at the point the system is presenting me with the desktop.  However, I get 6 or 7 display flickers followed by a warning.  hitting space to dismiss the warning I am presented with an option to start in low graphics mode.  The mouse doesn't work but I am able to 'tab' through the options (but not the radio button options, just the main elements) to 'click' ok.  Sometimes (but not always) a prompt comes up that says "Please wait one minutes while the display server restarts" but after one minute nothing.  Usually I'm able to hit CTRL+ALT+DEL and the system will reboot.

Tried: UEFI and BIOS boots.

Hardware: AMD A10 5750m (has integrated graphics) and Radeon 8670m discrete.

Other (possibly) useful information:  On ubuntu 12.04 with updated kernel (3.13.6) and updated open source drivers (mesa 9.10 i think) and latest xorg (I'm assuming we are not using MIR yet) the screen would change modes 3 times immediately on boot, but would complete the sequence and have hardware accel. on the desktop.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please help us help you by providing us with the information "a warning" isn't very helpful. Perhaps you could tell us what the warning was/is? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, so I clicked in "improve this answer" to my previous comment in order to add it.  However, after submitting it I found that it was ignored.  I tried to do it again and get the answer that I had too many answers rejected.  Then I tried to submit a new answer but was told that there was a limit of one per day.  So, I waited for a day and tried to "improve this answer" again - but I was told that it would be peer-reviewed, with a delay.  So I chose to post this as a new answer.

When I reported similar problem happened with motherboard ASRock P4i65GV and AGP Video card nVIDIA GeForce FX 5500, I was forgetting something: that this motherboard has a onboard video card Intel 82865G.

So I tried again, this time with one screen connected to the AGP nVIDIA card and another screen connected to the onboard Intel card.  The first try got the same crash result - but then I entered the BIOS Setup Utility, accessed the "Advanced" screen, and changed the "Init. Graphic Adapter Priority" from having Onboard in the last place to have it on the first place.  This way there are no glitches, the nVIDIA monitor is left without image, but the VGA monitor displays the desktop all right.  So, it is a problem strictly related to nVIDIA GeForce FX 5500 drivers.  And if you have more than one video card, remember to access BIOS to change their priority.

Maybe if I install Ubuntu now, later I will be able to get the nVIDIA card working properly.

Comment: This could be the answer to your own aforementioned question.