# Why doesn't it work to install Ubuntu? Please help!

Tags: system-installation, usb, amd-graphics, acer

I have tried so many times now but it doesn't work!
I have an Acer Aspire V with Windows 8.1 64-bit, 2.50 GHz AMD Quad-Core Processor A10-5757M, 512MB AMD Radeon HD 8650G Graphics System Memory, 8GB DDR3 Memory and 1TB (1000GB) HDD. I tried to install with USB because I don't have a DVD-Drive. I used Universal-USB-Installer, selected Ubuntu 64-bit, browsed and found ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso and selected it. I also selected the USB-Drive I will install it on and clicked Create. Then it installed Ubuntu on the USB. I restarted the computer with the USB-Stick plugged in. Then the Acer title screen started to blink. I tried to tap the F12 button but it either not worked! Please help! What do i need to do?

Comment: Try disabling safe boot.

Answer (score 0):

very similar issue just slightly different HW, safe boot is disabled (or just using legacy):

[boot for install crashes on 14.04 (Display related)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450193/boot-for-install-crashes-on-14-04-display-related)